# Google webfonts that support UTF-8 (Turkish) characters?

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

Does anybody know, which fonts support Turkish characters without a problem? Sans or Serif doesn't matter.

Example: İ Ü Ç Ğ Ö...

[image]

[image]

Comment: most fonts fonts from google fonts support utf-8. If you go to https://www.google.com/fonts and change the sample phrase to something with those latin characters you will see the font sets support them.  You may have an encoding problem with your page

Comment: Yes but majority goes all funny when using block capitals :/

Comment: Hmmm, what OS and browser are you using? do you have a link that I can test.  i am almost sure the problem is not the fonts, I work with Google fonts on a number of international projects here. almost all my  "font" problems were encoding.

Comment: Windows 7, Firefox, http://ythaber.com/.

Comment: Ah yeah those font suck :D Sorry for my ignorance, what langauge is this? have you tried "Ubuntu Mono"

Comment: No worries. It's Turkish. Ubuntu and some other fonts are displaying fine at Google Fonts. I'm trying it now on my website. Will add my own answer with a lot of typefaces if they display fine.

Comment: Update: Same issue with Duru and Ubuntu. 'İ' and 'Ğ' are the weird ones.

Comment: Ok buddy I think I found what you need, check this site: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/turkish

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller looks good

Comment: I would rephrase the question; you are probably looking for a font that supports all characters used in Turkish. Calling them UTF-8 characters is correct, but not very helpful. All common characters in all written languages in the world are also UTF-8 characters; UTF-8 is a character encoding standard that includes basically everything.

Comment: You are right Jeroen. I edited my question.

@samuel wonderful! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yeah JeroenHoek, when I read the question, it was easy to see there was more to this problem then a simple font issue. Now we have it narrowed down to a "font supporting Turkish" problem.

Comment: I can add the link as a separate response so you can mark it as correct ;)

Comment: Go for it :) However, still having issues with İ and Ğ in capitals :( Just ended it up editing my css -_- :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the fonts organized by language [here](http://fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/turkish).

Answer (score 15):

Actually google fonts comes with latin ext support you just have to add

`&subset=latin,latin-ext`

at end of defination of your font.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Yes, im turkish too :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way I've been doing it but does the fonts display properly in capitals this way? (Note: See the difference between Ö and the  rest on the attachment)

Comment: You can try byyourself too, we are using google fonts at most of our project, so far no issues, Öö Çç Ğğ and even İı no issues.

Comment: I must add, this is the best solution for google web fonts Turkish Char problem with something lacking: **IF** the font supports Turkish characters in google web fonts page then extending the url with `&subset=latin,latin-ext` will make the Turkish characters formatted correctly. So, what I always do with google web fonts is that I test the fonts by using my own text which is: **`gğ GĞ cç CÇ sş SŞ ıI iİ oö OÖ uü UÜ`** and then when using it in my projects extend the URL with `&subset=latin,latin-ext`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a lot of typefaces I found however some of them have display issues in capitals;

```
Neuton
Mouse Memoirs
Cutive
Yeseva One
Modern Antiqua
Autour One
Combo
Didact Gothic
Cutive
BenchNine
Warnes
EB Garamond
Parisienne
Francois One
Roboto
Forum
Patrick Hand
Almendra
Donegal
Galindo
Cardo
Ribeye
Ubuntu
Alegreya Sans
Duru Sans
Hammersmith One
Voces
Inconsolata
Poiret One
Unica One
Oregano
Andada
Scada
News Cycle
Enriqueta
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

- Audiowide
- Gafata
- Duru Sans
- Alegreya Sans SC

Comment: Was just looking at Duru Sans and Alegreya Sans. Thus, Ubuntu Mono working like a charm as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update your answers if met more?

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Bree+Serif
http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noto+Serif

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the font files, use the google webfonts helper below.
Make sure to check that the latin-ext subset of the font that you want to download exists there

https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/